# Finding minimum point of a function

Tags: vb.net, minimum

If I have a convex curve, and want to find the minimum point (x,y) using a for or while loop. I am thinking of something like

```
dim y as double
dim LastY as double = 0
for i = 0 to a large number
  y=computefunction(i)
  if lasty > y then exit for
next
```

how can I that minimum point? (x is always > 0 and integer)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722467/c-loop-to-find-minima-of-function

Comment: Depends on the curve. `y = -x^2` is convex, but has no minimum. Can you show us `computefunction`, or at least share the formula for the curve?

Comment: nature of computation is that its a convex curve, so it will have a minimum.

Comment: @theB: Any convex curve on a fixed interval will always have a minimum. Functions like `y = -x^2` can have two equal minimums, depending on how the interval is selected.

Comment: @Neolisk You're absolutely right. For whatever reason my brain completely decided to ignore the interval part. I still think though FWIW, that analysis of the function itself may give a simpler and more accurate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Very Close

you just need to

```
dim y as double
dim smallestY as double = computefunction(0)
for i = 0 to aLargeNumber as integer
    y=computefunction(i)
    if smallestY > y then smallestY=y
next
'now that the loop has finished, smallestY should contain the lowest value of Y
```

If this code takes a long time to run, you could quite easily turn it into a multi-threaded loop using parallel.For - for example

```
dim y as Double
dim smallestY as double = computefunction(0)
Parallel.For(0, aLargeNumber, Sub(i As Integer)
                                  y=computefunction(i)
                                  if smallestY > y then smallestY=y
                               End Sub)
```

This would automatically create separate threads for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Doing a linear search is the most inefficient you can get.

Comment: OK show us the best solution please.  So we can learn rather than just be criticised.

Comment: If I remember correctly from university, this is the right way to do it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search

Comment: OK maybe so, but @sjjohnson wanted to find the minimum using a for next loop. It might be worth asking for the parameters and compute function so that a comparison benchmark can be done.

Answer (score 1):

For a sample function:

```
y = 0.01 * (x - 50) ^ 2 - 5
```

or [properly written like this](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/index.php):

[image]

A minimum is [mathematically obvious](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Maximum-or-Minimum-Value-of-a-Quadratic-Function-Easily) at `x = 50` and `y = -5`, you can [verify with google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=y%20%3D%200.01%20*%20%28x%20-%2050%29%20%5E%202%20-%205):

[image]

Below VB.NET console application, [converted from python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search), finds a minimum at `x=50.0000703584199, y=-4.9999999999505`, which is correct for the specified tolerance of `0.0001`:

```
Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim result As Double = GoldenSectionSearch(AddressOf ComputeFunction, 0, 100)
    Dim resultString As String = "x=" & result.ToString + ", y=" & ComputeFunction(result).ToString
    Console.WriteLine(resultString) 'prints x=50.0000703584199, y=-4.9999999999505
  End Sub

  Function GoldenSectionSearch(f As Func(Of Double, Double), xStart As Double, xEnd As Double, Optional tol As Double = 0.0001) As Double
    Dim gr As Double = (Math.Sqrt(5) - 1) / 2

    Dim c As Double = xEnd - gr * (xEnd - xStart)
    Dim d As Double = xStart + gr * (xEnd - xStart)

    While Math.Abs(c - d) > tol
      Dim fc As Double = f(c)
      Dim fd As Double = f(d)

      If fc < fd Then
        xEnd = d
        d = c
        c = xEnd - gr * (xEnd - xStart)
      Else
        xStart = c
        c = d
        d = xStart + gr * (xEnd - xStart)
      End If
    End While

    Return (xEnd + xStart) / 2
  End Function

  Function ComputeFunction(x As Double)
    Return 0.01 * (x - 50) ^ 2 - 5
  End Function

End Module
```

**Side note**: your initial attempt to find minimum is assuming a function is discrete, which is very unlikely in real life. What you would get with a simple for loop is a very rough estimate, and a long time to find it, as linear search is least efficient among other methods.

Comment: Cool. Getting results from your function is considerably faster - to repeat the computation 1000 times took near enough the same amount of time as it took mine to do once in a non multithreaded computation Around 11ms. I rewrote my function to multi-thread it, and to run through the curve function in steps of .0001 to simulate your tolerances and it only took 36ms. Not bad for an inefficient function though eh? ;-) Oh and thanks for showing me the quickest way. It's appreciated

Comment: @DavidWilson: Increase search interval and/or tolerance to 0.000001, you should notice a difference. I'm generally leaning towards software engineering approach (simple + multi-threading, like you suggested), but in such a case you can't beat math. :)